# Firewalld Rules on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ssh, firewalld

I wanted to allow SSH within my Ubuntu 16.04 machine from a specific MAC address. I've tried the following:

Removed ssh services from the default zone - "public":

```
    firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --remove-service=ssh
```

Created a new zone:

```
    firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=secure
```

Allowed SSH:

```
    firewall-cmd --zone=secure --permanent --add-service=ssh
```

Added the MAC based access to access the ssh service:

```
    firewall-cmd --zone=secure --permanent --add-source=5c:f3:fc:30:47:e7
```

When I execute the active zone display command, it shows my network adaptor is already in the 'secure' zone:

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones

secure
    interfaces: enp1s0
    sources: 5C:F3:FC:30:47:E7
```

But even after rebooting my Ubuntu machine, I can ssh from any machine on my network. What may be the issue?

Comment: Can you post the default zone and the target of you secure zone. `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` and `firewalld-cmd --permanent --zone=secure --get-target`

Comment: Following is the output of the 'firewall-cmd --get-active-zones' command:

Comment: secure
  interfaces: enp1s0
  sources: 5C:F3:FC:30:47:E7

Comment: Following is the output of the 'firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=secure --get-target' command:      default

Comment: I suspect your target is ACCEPT , can you try `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=secure --set-target=REJECT`

Comment: I have tried the above and no luck so far. I have even set the target to DROP and tested. I can still SSH from any node located in my local network. But when I tried to ping the IP after changing it to the 'reject' target, ping started returning 'prohibited' message. So policies seems to be working but i'm missing with some rules. I've even verified the MAC address i have added. looks correct.